# Integer operand error

Tags: matlab

Hey I'm getting a strange error here. This function simply finds the proper divisors of a number and returns them.

```
function [divisors] = SOEdivisors(num)
%SOEDIVISORS This function finds the proper divisors of a number using the sieve
%of eratosthenes


    %check for primality
    if isprime(num) == 1
        divisors = [1];


    %if not prime find divisors
    else
        divisors = [0 2:num/2]; %hard code a zero at one.

        for i = 2:num/2
            if divisors(i) %if divisors i ~= 0

                %if the remainder is not zero it is a divisor
                if rem(num, divisors(i)) ~= 0

                    %remove that number and all its multiples from the list
                    divisors(i:i:num/2) = 0;
                end
            end
        end

        %add 1 back and remove all zeros
        divisors(1) = 1;
        divisors = divisors(divisors ~= 0);
    end
end
```

the error I receive is:

```
Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index
```

It refers to line 23.

Line 23 is

```
divisors(i:i:num/2) = 0;
```

But I i and num should both be integers... I know i is an integer. But even when I try

```
num = int8(num)
```

or something like that, I still get the error.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Actually if you force `num` to be of type int, you should not get this error (perhaps a different one). See `int8(5)/2` . ---- Sidenote: If you don't have to, dont force matlab to use numbers cast as integer, it may surprise you and will usually not be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `num` is an odd integer then `num/2` is not an integer...

Answer (score 0):

Your line only contains two parts used for indexing.

```
i
```

and

```
num/2
```

As you already mention that `i` and `num` are integers the only logical explanation is that `num` is odd.

Then `num/2` will not be integer.

---

Perhaps you are interested in using `fix(num/2)` (this is what will be used effectively for the cretion of `divisors`), or else perhaps `round` or `ceil`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using:

in code of command it means that you are know that the result is non point number for example 0.1 or 0.2 or 2.1 . You should have 1 or 2 or 21 .
also your result must be unsigned number .for example : 1 or 2 or 21 not -1 or -2 or -21.

Then use signed type of int or use from "`fix();`" command .
For example:

```
a=2.1;
```

`a=fix(a)`; then the "a" value will be 2 ;
Have good day.